# App crashes when launching App Info in the Settings

Tags: android

In my application, I want the user to tap a button to open the app info in the settings. This button is inside a Fragment.

If I press the button, the application crashes, throwing

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {
> act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
> dat=com.meltixdev.revomusicplayer }

The weird thing is that when I try to open `ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS` instead, the app opens the settings as it should.

This is what I did to start the Settings:

```
binding.btnPermission.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("com.meltixdev.revomusicplayer")))
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `package:` before your package name like below

```
binding.btnPermission.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:com.meltixdev.revomusicplayer")))
        }
```